# Text using sp for large layout looks different on two different large layout android screens

Tags: android

I have two tablets with 7 inch screens. I have designed a layout specifically for a large layout (res/layout-large). The two tablets have exactly the same dimensions (1024x600). I use sp to specify the text sizes. But the text on one tablet looks good and on another the text is much too large. I'm sure that it's the large layout xml that is being evokes (I did some checks with color of the text). I would assume since they are both the same dimensions, the text would look exactly the same on both screens. Why does the text look different at all? Am I doing something wrong with density vs size?

There is the xml ....

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="TOP"

            android:textSize="38sp"
        />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textBottom"
        style="@style/CategoryStyleBottom" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="(BOTTOM)"

        android:textSize="22sp"
     /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The tablets might have the same dimensions, but do they have the same pixel density? From what I understand, 'sp' is scale-independent measurement, so it will take a user's font size preference into consideration as well as pixel density.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Just for the sake of argument, if you flip your units to 'dp', do both devices draw the text font size the same? If so, maybe one of your tablets has a user-defined font size setting?

Comment: I did try switching to dp and I still had the problem. You`re probably right that it has something to do with the pixel density of the devices. But know that, how do I even figure out how big to make the font size? Thanks for the comment.

Comment: If you switched to 'dp', its probably not a user font preference, considering what the above docs say. I know the recommendation is to use 'sp' when it comes to text, but as to "how big to make a font size", I can't really say... depends on the project, sorry :-( But personally, I'd stick with Android Design guidelines: http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html - good luck, sorry that didn't help